# Use a locations ArrayList to draw a polyline into Google maps

Tags: java, android

I want to draw a `polyline` with an `ArrayList` of locations. I already tried with an `ArrayList` of `LatLng` and it works well.

```
 options2.addAll(places).width(5).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);
 polyline = mMap.addPolyline(options2);
```

places is a `ArrayList` of `LatLng`:

```
final List<LatLng> places = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

The problem is that I can't use `.addAll()` method with an `ArrayList` of locations. I even tried to create another `ArrayList` of `LatLng` and put in it, the latitude and longitude of locations. I face an error while doing such. Any suggestion?

Comment: What was the error, you can use a for loop for location's ArrayList size and add every value to it by `cordList.add(new LatLng(loaction(i).getLatitude,location(i).getLongitude));`. I can suggest a way if you can provide some code or the error.